# reposition object in circle

Tags: java, math, libgdx, trigonometry

As you can see on the image, I have a p1 and p2 objects with (x,y) coordinates which I know the values, and I know radius of all these circle objects.

However, I want to calculate new position x,y which would be p3 center point. Basically, as you can see it's p2 position + radius.

I am doing this for java game which is based on libgdx. I would appreciate any math or java language directions/examples.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462239/how-to-move-point-along-circle which contains a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: And the following links contains code for the transformation between polar co-ordinates and x-y co-ordinates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576502/how-do-you-convert-between-polar-coordinates-and-cartesian-coordinates-assuming

Comment: Thank you for this links, I already found some of these. To be honest regarding first link from the stackoverflow and that answer which states: `a1 = 28*(π/180)` where 28 is moving angle in case of that question, and that variable value i don't have in my case. In  my case I know only positions and radius. But I believe I will come something up with from other links you provided. :)

Comment: `a1 = 28*(π/180)` is the conversion of 28 degrees into the corresponding amount of radians, (360° = 2π). The distance from p2 to p3 can be expressed as way on the big circle (in radians) or as angle between the lines p1p2 and p1p3 (in degrees).

Comment: The issue is also discussed at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/moving-an-object-in-a-circular-path

Comment: This is also good link! Thank a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code comments for explanation.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.*;

class CenteredCircle extends Ellipse2D.Double {
    CenteredCircle(Point2D.Double p, double radius) {
        super(p.x - radius, p.y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }   
}

public class CircleDemo extends JFrame {
    public CircleDemo() {
            int width = 640; int height = 480;
            setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
    
            JPanel p = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    // center p1
                    Point2D.Double p1 = new Point2D.Double(getSize().width/2, getSize().height/2);
                    double radius = 130.0;

                    // big circle
                    Shape circle2 = new CenteredCircle(p1, radius);
                    g2d.draw(circle2);                    

                    // 12 small circles
                    for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 30) {
                        // this is the magic part
                        // a polar co-ordinate has a length and an angle
                        // by changing the angle we rotate
                        // the transformed co-ordinate is the center of the small circle
                        Point2D.Double newCenter = polarToCartesian(radius, angle);
                        // draw line just for visualization
                        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + newCenter.x, p1.y+ newCenter.y);
                        g2d.draw(line);
                        // draw the small circle
                        Shape circle = new CenteredCircle(
                            new Point2D.Double(p1.x + newCenter.x, p1.y + newCenter.y),
                            radius/4);
                        g2d.draw(circle);  
                    }
                }
            };
            setTitle("Circle Demo");
            getContentPane().add(p);
        }
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CircleDemo();
            }
        });
    }    
    static Point2D.Double polarToCartesian(double r, double theta) {
        theta = (theta * Math.PI) / 180.0; // multiply first, then divide to keep error small
        return new Point2D.Double(r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta));
    }
    // not needed, just for completeness
    public static Point2D.Double cartesianToPolar(double x, double y) {
        return new Point2D.Double(Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y), (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180) / Math.PI);
    }    
}
```

[image: Circle with small circle along]

Answer (score 1):

Now using *libgdx* for the graphics. Thus no need for polar co-ordinates, on the outside.

I am not doing frame rate relative animation. Therefore, this is no perfect match to your code.

Using the following calculation (`if (theta >= 360) { theta = 0.0f; }`) at the end of the render method will let the animation restart with its original value.

```java
package org.demo;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;

public class CircleDemo extends ApplicationAdapter {
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    float theta = 0.0f;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1);

        Vector2 p1 = new Vector2( Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2.0f ,  Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2.0f);
        Vector2 smallCircleCenter = new Vector2(150.0f, 0.0f);
        smallCircleCenter.add(p1); // translate center by p1

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

        // static lines and circles
        for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 30) {
            Vector2 lineEnd = new Vector2(smallCircleCenter);
            lineEnd.rotateAroundDeg(p1, angle);
            shapeRenderer.line(p1, lineEnd);
            shapeRenderer.circle(lineEnd.x, lineEnd.y, 20);
        }

        // animated line and circle in red
        shapeRenderer.setColor(0.75f, 0, 0, 1);
        Vector2 movingCircleCenter = new Vector2(smallCircleCenter);
        movingCircleCenter.rotateAroundDeg(p1, theta);
        shapeRenderer.line(p1, movingCircleCenter);
        shapeRenderer.circle(movingCircleCenter.x, movingCircleCenter.y, 20);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

        shapeRenderer.end();
        theta++;

        // for the screenshot stop at 90 degrees
        if (theta >= 90) {
            theta = 90.0f;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image: Circle drawn with libgdx]

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a test in my project, based on your approach:

```
package com.bigbang.test.impl;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.bigbang.Game;
import com.bigbang.graphics.g2d.shapes.impl.Ellipse;
import com.bigbang.graphics.g2d.shapes.impl.Line;
import com.bigbang.graphics.gl.Color;
import com.bigbang.math.BBMath;

public class PolarToCartesianTest extends AbstractTest {

    private Array<GraphicalObject> graphicalObjectArray;
    private GraphicalObject dynamicGraphicalObject;
    private float radius, smallCircleRadius;
    private float centerX, centerY;

    public PolarToCartesianTest(Game game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        radius = 200f;
        centerX = game.getScreenController().getScreenWidth() / 2;
        centerY = game.getScreenController().getScreenHeight() / 2;
        smallCircleRadius = radius / 4;
        graphicalObjectArray = new Array<>();
        for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 30) {
            GraphicalObject graphicalObject = new GraphicalObject();
            graphicalObject.angle = angle;
            graphicalObjectArray.add(graphicalObject);
        }
        dynamicGraphicalObject = new GraphicalObject();

        game.getCameraController().getCamera().position.x = game.getScreenController().getScreenWidth() / 2;
        game.getCameraController().getCamera().position.y = game.getScreenController().getScreenHeight() / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        for (GraphicalObject graphicalObject : graphicalObjectArray) {
            Vector2 polarToCartesianPosition = BBMath.polarToCartesian(radius, graphicalObject.angle);

            graphicalObject.line.x1 = centerX + 0;
            graphicalObject.line.y1 = centerY + 0;
            graphicalObject.line.x2 = centerX + polarToCartesianPosition.x;
            graphicalObject.line.y2 = centerY + polarToCartesianPosition.y;
            graphicalObject.line.color = Color.WHITE_COLOR;

            graphicalObject.ellipse.x = centerX + polarToCartesianPosition.x;
            graphicalObject.ellipse.y = centerY + polarToCartesianPosition.y;
            graphicalObject.ellipse.width = 2 * smallCircleRadius;
            graphicalObject.ellipse.height = 2 * smallCircleRadius;
            graphicalObject.ellipse.color = Color.WHITE_COLOR;
        }

        float shift = 0;
        float theta = (shift * smallCircleRadius) * (centerY / centerX);
        Vector2 pos = BBMath.polarToCartesian(radius, theta);
        dynamicGraphicalObject.line.color = new Color(Color.RED);
        dynamicGraphicalObject.line.x1 = centerX + 0;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.line.y1 = centerY + 0;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.line.x2 = centerX + pos.x;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.line.y2 = centerY + pos.y;

        dynamicGraphicalObject.ellipse.x = centerX + pos.x;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.ellipse.y = centerY + pos.y;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.ellipse.width = 2 * smallCircleRadius;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.ellipse.height = 2 * smallCircleRadius;
        dynamicGraphicalObject.ellipse.color = new Color(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        game.getShapeRenderer().begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        for (GraphicalObject graphicalObject : graphicalObjectArray) {
            graphicalObject.line.draw();
            graphicalObject.ellipse.draw();
        }
        dynamicGraphicalObject.line.draw();
        dynamicGraphicalObject.ellipse.draw();
        game.getShapeRenderer().end();
    }

    class GraphicalObject {
        Ellipse ellipse;
        Line line;
        float angle;

        public GraphicalObject() {
            this.ellipse = new Ellipse(game);
            this.line = new Line(game);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is same math like in your example, with some modifications:

[image]

However, you can notice I have this dynamicGraphicalObject (red circle), which I want to shift position around circle by using theta value calculated as `(shift * smallCircleRadius) * (centerY / centerX);`. This works perfect for shift=0 value. It's properly positioned/overlapping white. But if I would change shift variable to 1, 2, 3, or 11, you can see that it's not precisely aligned with white circles. Is this floating point issue or am I missing something in calculation of theta ?
shift values used: 2,6 and 11 in order by images

[image]

[image]

[image]

--

SOLUTION:

```
float fixPrecision = 1.1f;
float theta = (shift * fixPrecision) + ((shift * smallCircleRadius) * (centerY / centerX));
```

Comment: Just log/print the values for `theta` after (`float theta = (shift * smallCircleRadius) * (centerY / centerX);`). You will see that the angle slightly differs and does not match the values 30, 60, ..., 270. Your pictures also show that the distance to p1 is correct. So you are not too far off. You might use `double` to reduce the error in the calculation. You can also change your calculation to `(shift * smallCircleRadius * centerY ) / centerX` and see if the derivation gets reduced. As alternative you can round the calculation to a multiple of `30` if theta is close to it.

Comment: btw libdgx's vector2 class has a rotate methode you could use: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#rotateDeg-float-

Comment: `(shift * smallCircleRadius * centerY ) / centerX` would give the same result. But rounding would fix it. So I will go with this one.